# How to store a variable number of dynamic keys in a key value map

Tags: apigee

I have a policy that needs to generate the hash for a variable number of links contained in the response payload. I can create a javascript policy that generates these hashes and add them as flow vars. However I don't know how to store these vars into either a key value map or a cache, because the var names are dynamic not static.

For example....

For a response payload looking like this...

{
"link1": "http://link1",
"link2": "http://link2"
}

My javascript policy adds the following flow vars link.{linkhash1}, link.{linkhash2}.

I want to now store these in either a key value map or a cache. However both of these policies require a fixed variable name, but in this case the var names are dynamic i.e only known at runtime. Ideally I would like to manipulate the cache/kv map directly from the javascript policy itself.

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to access the KVM or Cache from within JavaScript executed by a JS policy at some point in proxy flows, it is possible to access and store into Apigee Cache from within Node.js code, using the apigee-access node module.
See: http://community.apigee.com/questions/6467/edge-how-to-interact-with-key-value-map-from-javas.html

So, what you'll have to do is configure your proxy backend to be a Node.js application, and from within that application, you can handle requests and route to target backend, and from the target response payload, you can then extract the links, hash them and set the variables in cache.
Take a look at: http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/using-apigee-access